# How to Change trash button' color in Objective-C?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

I have this code, it creates a blue trash can icon on the navigation bar, I want to change the color of this icon to black. how can i do it?
Here is my code:

```
//add trash button to navigation bar
    UIBarButtonItem *myTrash = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem: UIBarButtonSystemItemTrash
                                                                             target: self
                                                                            action: @selector(deleteHandler)];

    NSArray* barButtons = [self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItems arrayByAddingObject: myTrash];
    self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItems = barButtons;
```

Comment: Please do enough research before posting a question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try changing the tint color of the whole window (Which will help you achieve a consistent color theme):

`self.window.tintColor = [UIColor blackColor];`

Or the navigation bar's appearance:

`[UINavigationBar appearance].tintColor = [UIColor blackColor];`